# Classification schemes for icons

Tags: icon

Is there a standard classification scheme used by graphic designers for icons to help identify the characteristics of icon designs?

I am not referring to things that describe the physical characteristics (e.g. 32px x 32px or file size), but style characteristics or the nature of the image (e.g. noun vs. action or abstract vs. detailed).

For example, iconfinder.com uses **Categories** and **Styles** on top of keyword terms, but it is still quite difficult to find or describe the icons clear enough to communicate the design elements.

Just wondering if things such as defining the icons as 'objects' or 'actions' or 'descriptions' and also describing the style and complexity of the design (single or multiple objects in the design) would make it more useful for people to find and design them.

Comment: Flaticon only has flat icons, so leaves style out of the question. They use [categories](http://www.flaticon.com/categories/) as well. To name a few: Animals, Arrows, Art, Buildings, Business, Cinema, Commerce...

Comment: Actually, never heard about such things with my 13 years of experience as pro :)

Comment: @Vnovak Would you find it helpful though? But I guess if you have never needed it as a professional then it is probably not as useful as I think it might be.

Comment: Probably it can be useful inside your design team or community, but clients you will work don't know about such classifications for sure and just will provide samples for you.

Comment: Both of these questions you asked... I haven't got the slightest idea of what you might be getting at.  --- What you're thinking of, as far as I can tell, is used all the time.

Comment: @Joonas I think it comes to good graphic designers naturally, but as far as being able to create a consistent visual language for different user interfaces and different communication channels, I don't think visual designers and interface designers think the same way about this.

Comment: Personally I think that clients don't need classifications and designers don't really care. They only care if the icons work well together, with is not always quantifiable. So I guess the only people who need these categories are the ones that **buy iconsets**. So, the only use is to find icons in a larger set. Which is exactly the same as shopping for anything else, making the a search-optimization question :)

Answer (score 1):

To recap, what I said before. Here is presented some kind of different terms like 3d, simple, complex, flat, lineart, etc.. but even designers understand each of them in a bit different way. This is why specific visual references is the most effective way to be sure that everybody at the same track.